# How to display Arabic numerals with \ref but Roman numerals otherwise?

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, chapters, roman-numerals

To show all chapter numbers as Roman numerals, I’m using

```
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}
```

The fourth chapter, for instance, is therefore “Chapter IV” everywhere.

Is it possible to show the numbers as Arabic numerals *only* when referencing to chapters using `\ref{...}`?

Using the example above, `\ref{chapter-four}` would result in “Chapter 4” instead of “Chapter IV.”

Comment: sounds a little like [How do I get a chapter \ref in counting numbers when the ToC uses Roman numerals?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80543)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Patching `\@makechapterhead` to print `\Roman{chapter}` instead of `\thechapter` allows you to have chapter headings formatting with Roman numerals yet have references inside your text to still be Arabic:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}% <cmd>
  {\thechapter}% <search>
  {\Roman{chapter}}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
\begin{document}
%\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}\label{chap-label}
See Chapter~\ref{chap-label}.
\end{document}
```

Note that numbering inside your ToC will also be Arabic. To change this, a patch to `\@chapter` is required (also wrapped inside a `\makeatletter`-`\makeatother`-pair):

```
\patchcmd{\@chapter}% <cmd>
  {\numberline{\thechapter}}% <search>
  {\numberline{\Roman{chapter}}}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
```