# Roman part numbering, but Roman and arabic output for \ref

Tags: memoir, arabic, roman

In the `memoir` class, the `\part` is defined with a Roman number count. However, the `memoir` options to change number 1 into "first" or "one" by `\ordinaltoname{\getrefnumber{part:label}}` or `\numtoname{\getrefnumber{part:label}}` only work for arabic number references. Is there a possibility to redefine a \ref{Roman number} to \ref{arabic number}? I would like to use both Part I (Roman ref output) and Part one (arabic ref output) in my part pages.

This answer seems to work for chapters, however, changing chapter in part doesn't seem to work for my case: [How do I get a chapter \ref in counting numbers when the ToC uses Roman numerals?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80543/how-do-i-get-a-chapter-ref-in-counting-numbers-when-the-toc-uses-roman-numerals/80548#80548)

```
\documentclass{memoir}% in XeLaTeX

\begin{document}

\part{Introduction}\label{part:intro}

I would like to refer to the part number by the standard Roman number input 
for \ref{part:intro} giving the Roman output Part I.
And also by the arabic number input Part 1 with let's say \refarabic 
for \numtoname{\refarabic{part:intro}} to obtain the output Part one.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal working example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is not expandable, but provides you with what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{refcount,etoolbox}

\def\partnumbername#1{%
  \edef\x{\getrefnumber{#1}}%
  \expandafter\numtoname\expandafter{\expandafter\rmntonum\expandafter{\x}}}

\begin{document}

\part{Introduction}\label{part:intro}

Part~\ref{part:intro}.

Part~\getrefnumber{part:intro}.

Part~\partnumbername{part:intro}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you very much!

Comment: Werner, I have provided an answer that extends yours, which I am amazed at and don't really understand. If you wish to add the extension to your answer then I am not unhappy to delete my rather rambling response.

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with this and then @Werner came up with an answer. In my struggles I was first trying to get the referenced Roman number converted to an arabic numeral which could then be typeset as a name. I failed on the first part of this. I tried Heiko Oberdiek's code for chapters [How do I get a chapter \ref in counting numbers when the ToC uses Roman numerals?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80543) hoping to write a part version but his original code had compilation errors. My feeble attempts went nowhere.

Below is my code, which includes my failed attempts and an extension to @Werner's code to enable the conversion of a Roman part number into an arabic number, thus providing a bit more generality.

```
% mempartnoprob.tex  SE  588204
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{comment}
%%%%%% code based on Heiko Oberdiek  SE 80543 which didn't work
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
\protected\def\ArabicRomanChapter#1#2{#2}%
\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{%
  \ArabicRomanChapter{\arabic{chapter}}{\Roman{chapter}}%
}
\renewcommand*{\p@chapter}{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  \@p@chapter}
\newcommand*{\@p@chapter}[3]{#2}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{My chapter}
\label{chap:my}
See chapter \ref{chap:my}.
\end{document}  

\end{comment}

\begin{comment}
%% my code attempts which didn't work
\newcommand*{\rtoaref}[1]{\arabic{\ref{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\rtoaref}[1]{\arabic{{\ref{#1}}}}
\renewcommand*{\rtoaref}[1]{\expandafter\arabic{\ref{#1}}}
%\renewcommand*{\rtoaref}[1]{\ref{\arabic{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\part{First} \label{apart}

This text is in \ref{apart}. 

This text is in \rtoaref{apart}. 

\end{comment}

%%%% This code from Werner in answer to the question.

%%\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{refcount,etoolbox}

\def\partnumbername#1{%
  \edef\x{\getrefnumber{#1}}%
  \expandafter\numtoname\expandafter{\expandafter\rmntonum\expandafter{\x}}}

%%%% my extension to get the number ref'd as arabic instead of Roman
\def\partnumberarabic#1{%
  \edef\x{\getrefnumber{#1}}%
  \expandafter\rmntonum\expandafter{\x}}  

\begin{document}

\part{Introduction}\label{part:intro}

Part~\ref{part:intro}.

Part~\getrefnumber{part:intro}.

Part~\partnumbername{part:intro}.

Part~\partnumberarabic{part:intro}.

\end{document}
```

[image]