# Display \ref results with small caps roman numerals (French typographical rules)

Tags: typography, french, roman-numerals, labelling

[According to French typographical rules](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/volume-I/cabochon-citation.html), chapters heading have to be in Roman numerals caps and references to chapters have to be written with small caps Roman numerals. Modifying chapter headings is easy with scrbook which I am using (I redefine `chapterformat`), but I have hard time converting references to a chapter in small caps Roman numeral.

I tried using `\usepackage{modroman}` to display Roman numbers.

Something like `\textsc{\nblongRoman{\ref{chapter:lechapitre}}}` unfortunately doesn't work (I think because it is a counter and not a number). Is there some simple way to display the number returned by a reference as a Roman number?

**Note** :
The label is of course something like :

```
\chapter{Le chapitre}
\label{chapter:lechapitre}
```

---

---

### TL;DR

I have some label to a chapter written as :

```
\chapter{Le chapitre}
\label{chapter:lechapitre}
```

By default, `voir le chapitre \ref{chapter:lechapitre}` returns :

"voir le chapitre 2"

I want this to be displayed as

"voir le chapitre ɪɪ" (small caps Roman numerals)

---

Some example that is not working:

```
\documentclass[12pt,
            a4paper,
            DIV=10,
            headinclude=true,
            footinclude=false,
            chapterprefix=true
        ]{scrbook}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}     

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Le chapitre}
\label{chapter:lechapitre}

voir le chapitre \ref{chapter:lechapitre}
\end{document}
```

Comment: show a small but complete example. That makes it much easier to test solutions.

Comment: Ok, I added a TL;DR to make it simple. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: It would be best to have a complete (but short) document for copy&paste.

Comment: Ok I added a complete doc at the end.

Comment: Unrelated, but why are you using the `fontenc` and `polyglossia`, since the latter is designed for use with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX?

Comment: @alanMunn I'm indeed using XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can adapt the answer given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80543/2693) to achieve what you want.

```
\documentclass[12pt,
            a4paper,
            DIV=10,
            headinclude=true,
            footinclude=false,
            chapterprefix=true
        ]{scrbook}

\makeatletter
\protected\def\SCRomanChapter#1#2{#2}
\providecommand\@secondofthree[3]{#2}
\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{%
  \SCRomanChapter{\textsc{\roman{chapter}}}{\Roman{chapter}}%
}
\labelformat{chapter}{\expandafter\@secondofthree#1}
\makeatother  

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Le chapitre}
\label{chapter:lechapitre}

voir le chapitre \ref{chapter:lechapitre}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Nice solution, thanks!